# What on hit effects are in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can't find what other 'on hit' effects are in Diablo 3. I know of knockback and life on hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The existing on-hit effects are

- Bleed
- Blind
- Chill
- Fear
- Freeze
- Immobilize
- Knockback
- Life
- Mana (WD only)
- Slow
- Stun

Of these +life and +mana are unique in the fact that they always work; the others only come in the form of "chance to" affixes. I've excluded life steal from this list because it isn't formally "per hit".